# Doubt in Urysohn's lemma

Tags: general-topology, analysis

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $O$ is open in $X,$ then by Urysohn's lemma there exists a continuous function $f:X \to [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in X \setminus O.$

My question is, can we find a function $f$ with an added assumption that $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in O?$

(I need this to prove something related to multiplication operators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure!
$$f(x)=\min(\mathrm{dist}(x,X\setminus O), 1)$$